# org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Error during certificate path validation: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors

Tags: java, security, ssl, soap, cxf

I am working on creating a web service client to connect to a service. I followed the following steps to create and connect to service using certificate authentication

1. Downloaded certificate from browser after executing wsdl URL and installed in cacerts by using the command

   ```
   keytool -importcert -alias aliasname -file abc.cer -keystore cacerts -storepass storepwd
   ```

   or

   generated certificate from jks with the following command

   ```
   keytool -export -alias key -file xxxx.cer -keystore xxxx.jks
   ```

   then added above generated certificate to trustore

   ```
   keytool -importcert -alias aliasname -file abc.cer -keystore cacerts -storepass storepwd
   ```
2. Generated client code using cxf3.0.13, java 6, eclipse
3. created the following security properties

   ```
   org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider=
   org.apache.ws.security.components.Merlin
   org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type=jks
   org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.file=xxxx.jks
   org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password=key-pass
   org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.truststore.file=cacerts
   org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.truststore.password=cacertspwd
   ```
4. In the cxf generated client class I added the following

   ```
   Service service = new Service(wsdlurl, service_name);
   ServicePort port = service.getServicePort();
   ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put("ws-security.signature.properties", "security.properties");
   ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put("ws-security.encryption.properties", "security.properties");
   ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put("ws-security.signature.username", "xxxxx");
   ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put("ws-security.encryption.username", "xxxxx");
   ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put("ws-security.callback-handler", "com.abc.ClientCallbackHandler");

   SearchResult result = port.search("abc");
   ```
5. Created ClientCallbackHandler as specified in https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jws13/index.html

   ```
   public class ClientCallbackHandler implements CallbackHandler {
       public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException {
           for (int i = 0; i < callbacks.length; i++) {
               WSPasswordCallback pwcb = (WSPasswordCallback) callbacks[i];
               String id = pwcb.getIdentifier();
               int usage = pwcb.getUsage();
               if (usage == WSPasswordCallback.DECRYPT
                       || usage == WSPasswordCallback.SIGNATURE) {
                   // used to retrieve password for private key
                   if ("clientkey".equals(id)) {
                       pwcb.setPassword("key-pass");
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

After running the client class, I am getting the following error

```
org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doDefaultLogging
WARNING: Interceptor for {http://www.xxxxxxx.com}Service#{http://www.xxxxxxx.com}Search has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Error during certificate path validation: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JUtils.createSoapFault(WSS4JUtils.java:275)
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessageInternal(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:333)
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:190)
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor.java:128)
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor.java:112)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:802)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1682)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1559)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1356)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:653)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:516)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:425)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:326)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:279)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:138)
        at $Proxy44.search(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: Error during certificate path validation: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
Original Exception was java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
        at org.apache.wss4j.common.crypto.Merlin.verifyTrust(Merlin.java:970)
        at org.apache.wss4j.dom.validate.SignatureTrustValidator.verifyTrustInCerts(SignatureTrustValidator.java:108)
        at org.apache.wss4j.dom.validate.SignatureTrustValidator.validate(SignatureTrustValidator.java:64)
        at org.apache.wss4j.dom.processor.SignatureProcessor.handleToken(SignatureProcessor.java:185)
        at org.apache.wss4j.dom.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(WSSecurityEngine.java:428)
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessageInternal(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:278)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.wss4j.common.crypto.Merlin.verifyTrust(Merlin.java:951)
        ... 25 more
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Error during certificate path validation: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:160)
        at $Proxy44.search(Unknown Source)
       Caused by: org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: Error during certificate path validation: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
Original Exception was java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
        at org.apache.wss4j.common.crypto.Merlin.verifyTrust(Merlin.java:970)
        at org.apache.wss4j.dom.validate.SignatureTrustValidator.verifyTrustInCerts(SignatureTrustValidator.java:108)
        at org.apache.wss4j.dom.validate.SignatureTrustValidator.validate(SignatureTrustValidator.java:64)
        at org.apache.wss4j.dom.processor.SignatureProcessor.handleToken(SignatureProcessor.java:185)
        at org.apache.wss4j.dom.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(WSSecurityEngine.java:428)
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessageInternal(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:278)
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:190)
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor.java:128)
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor.java:112)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:802)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1682)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1559)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1356)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:653)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:516)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:425)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:326)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:279)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:138)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.wss4j.common.crypto.Merlin.verifyTrust(Merlin.java:951)
        ... 25 more
```

What I am doing wrong here. Could anyone please help me

Answer (score 0):

`wss4j` is validating the soap signing certificate, which does not have to be the SSL certificate you used when downloading the WSDL.

You need to import in the truststore the certificate used by server to sign the soap message. Options

1. Request it you service provider
2. Log a SOAP response and extract it from the X509Certificate node of the XML signature,

.

```
<KeyInfo>
  <X509Data>
     <X509Certificate>MIID5jCCA0+gA...lVN</X509Certificate>
  </X509Data>
</KeyInfo>
```

Comment: I didnt find anything related to X509Certificate node in the sopa response. I found BinarySecurityToken under <soap:header><security>. Is this is what you are referring to.

Comment: It could be, BinarySecurityToken can also contain the certificate and be referenced from `ds:KeyInfo` like [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGMCP_5.1.0/com.ibm.cics.ts.webservices.doc/wsSecurity/dfhws_soapmsg_signed.html). XML Signatures are too complex. Look for a base64 field starting with `MII` and named as 'x509', or post and example. In any case, the service provider should send you the certification chain

Comment: I extracted the certificate from SOAP header and verified which is already present in my JKS file

Comment: Maybe it's an unnecessary clarification, but you need to add the certificate to the truststore "cacerts" not to the keystore .jks

Comment: Did that also. But not working. Could you please let me know is there any way that we can disable server signature validation after receiving response.
When I added -Djavax.net.debug=all JVM argument I am able to see the response in encrypted and decrypted form. After receiving the server signature validation it is failing and getting the above mentioned exception. Hoping if I disable this validation will help in proceeding further.

Comment: The problem is not with SSL connection. If this were the problem, the connection to the server would not be established and you would not have a SOAP response. I do not know how to disable wss4j trust verification. Theis issue could be originated because the server has misconfigured the certifcation chain, but if you added the leaf certificate to the truststore, it should dissapear. Could you use SOAP UI to execute the SOAP request and validate it? Then inspect the result and check  if the certificate that it is validating SOAP UI is the same as yours

Comment: I cant use SOAPUI. Only approved software I can use. What is leaf certificate, how can I find that and add to trust store.